# How do I terminate parent thread from child?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, exit

How do I terminate the parent (main) thread from a child thread created my main? I tried System.exit(1) but it only terminate the child thread. I also tried putting a condition in main's while loop but it will obviously try to read 1 extra input before exiting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    { 
      public void run() 
      { 
        while(true) 
        { 
            //meet a condition then terminate
        } 
      } 
    }).start(); 
    while (true)
    {
        String a = input.nextLine();
        //do something with input
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.exit(1)` terminates _all_ threads. To answer your question, you cannot - `input.nextLine` is **blocking** and **non-interruptible** so once you start waiting for input you cannot stop.

Comment: if I do the opposite, calling System.exit(1) in main's while loop, will it terminate the child?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-): _Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine._ `System.exit` exits the whole JVM. **All** threads exit. The JVM terminates. That's it. You shouldn't be using it in any case - there is almost never a good use case for it.

Comment: B.T.W., "Parent" and "Child" have no meaning in Java threading.  Thread _groups_ can have a parent/child relationship, and every Thread belongs to a ThreadGroup, but if thread A creates thread B, the library does not grant either thread any special rights, or capabilities with respect to the the other, nor does it remember which one created which.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do this. It's a really bad idea to terminate any thread from outside that thread. This is because the terminating thread has no idea what the target is doing and whether it is at a "safe" point to terminate. For example you might be in the middle of writing output, or making calculations, or anything.

Instead you should send a signal to the other thread (using any one of a number of means) and that thread exits itself. To exit a thread just return from the thread's run method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I might have to try a different way for server to signal the client when it's safe to exit then. I always encounter some socketbinding exception when the client exits first. Also, if I end the parent (main) thread, will it terminate the child's thread?

Answer (score 1):

Kill a `Thread` from it's children it's not a good practice, but you can program the children thread to update a field from the parent. if this field is not null parent should stop.

Also [take a look to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123245/killing-child-thread-from-parent-thread-in-java)